# JavaScript type writer effect changing from onclick to onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the code I have. I want to make a  type writer effect work purely on javascript. If you have any thoughts or better code, please share.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Typewriter</h1>

<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How to make it load instantly once page loads.

Comment: Just call `typeWriter()` ??

Comment: Add `typeWriter();` before `</script>` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do that.

1. You can write typewriter as an IIFE(Immediately invoked function expression): [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)
2. You can call the function manually before the  tag
3. You can use window.onload method to execute the function when the page loads:[onload method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)